# Как вывести наибольшее значение массива?

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм

Читаю «Язык Си» Стивена Прата. Остановился на упражнениях по программированию (глава 10):

> Напишите функцию, которая возвращает наибольшее значение из массива зна­чений типа int. Протестируйте эту функцию с помощью простой программы.

То есть функция должна принимать в аргументах сам массив (int) и возвращать наибольшее значение. Что сделал я:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 7
int max(int*,int);
int main(void){
        int arr[SIZE] = {9,2,3,4,7,55,6};
        printf("%d\n",max(arr,SIZE));
}
int max(int *arr, int v){
        int arr2[v];
        int a,b,c;
        for(a=0;a<v;a++){
                arr2[a]=arr[a];
        }
        for(a=0;a<v;a++){
                for(b=1;b<v;b++){
                        if(arr2[b]>arr2[b-1]){
                                c=arr2[b];
                                arr2[b]=arr2[b-1];
                                arr2[b-1]=c;
                        }
                }
        }
        return arr2[0];
}
```

---

Использовал алгоритм сортировки (нубский) и записал в другой массив дабы не менять старый.
Так вот вопрос, как правильнее было бы решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 7
int max(int*,int);
int main(void){
        int arr[SIZE] = {9,2,3,4,7,55,6};
        printf("%d\n",max(arr,SIZE));
}
int max(int *arr, int v){
    int max = arr[0];
    for(int i=1;i<v;i++){
         if(max<arr[i])   
            max = arr[i];    
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Мгм, взять и найти максимум?

```
int max = arr[0];
int i;
for(i = 1; i < v; ++i) if(arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
return max;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ужас какой, ну вы и нагородили. Задачка-то проще некуда.

```
int ArrayMax(int* arr, int arrSize) {
    int retVal = INT_MIN;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i) {
        if (retVal < arr[i]) retVal = arr[i];
    }
    return retVal;
}
```